# Recebendo Json array em PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou com o seguinte código no lado da aplicação:

```
function enviaMensagem() { 
    var send = "http://appchat.host56.com/mensagem.php?jsoncallback=?";
$.post( send, {"table": [{"d":1, "p":1, "m": "1"},{"d":2, "p":2, "m": "2"},{"d":3, "p":3, "m": "3"}]}, function( data ) {}, "json");

}
```

No lado do servidor eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($json, true);
$table = $jsonObj->table; 
foreach ( $table as $e ) { 
\\aqui eu gravo o resultado em um BD
}
```

Quando eu passo apenas uma cadeia de dados, sem ter um table, eu consigo manipular ex:
 `$.post( send, {"d":1, "p":1, "m": "1"}, function( data ) {}, "json");`, mas passando um table não.

Como faço para pegar os dados `table[0]['d']`?

---

Lado da aplicação

```
<script>
    var newUsers = [];

            newUser = {};
            newUser['nome'] = 'alvaro';
            newUser['idade'] = '34';
            newUsers.push(JSON.stringify(newUser));

            newUser1 = {};
            newUser1['nome'] = 'bia';
            newUser1['idade'] = '7';
            newUsers.push(JSON.stringify(newUser1));

            newUser2 = {};
            newUser2['nome'] = 'alice';
            newUser2['idade'] = '2';
            newUsers.push(JSON.stringify(newUser2));

            $.ajax({
                url: "mensagem.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'newUsers[]': newUsers
                },
                success: function () {

                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });

<\script>
```

No lado do server php tenho:

```
if (isset($_POST['newUsers'])) {
    $newUsers = $_POST['newUsers'];
    var_dump($newUsers);
    foreach ($newUsers as $user) {
        $usr = json_decode($user,false);
        var_dump($usr);
        echo($usr->nome);
    }
}
?>
```

No primeiro var_dump do $newUsers ele tem o resultado: `array(3) { [0]=> string(38) "{\"nome\":\"alvaro\",\"idade\":\"34\"}" [1]=> string(34) "{\"nome\":\"bia\",\"idade\":\"7\"}" [2]=> string(36) "{\"nome\":\"alice\",\"idade\":\"2\"}"}`    e no segundo tenho:  `NULLNULLNULL` não sei como tratar isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que está a pedir uma array associativa quando passa `true` como segundo parametro do `json_decode`.

Se usar `json_decode($json, true)` tem de usar `$table = $jsonObj['table'];`.

Se passar `false` fazendo `json_decode($json, false)` vai receber um objeto e aí `$table = $jsonObj->table;` já vai funcionar.

#### Exemplo: http://ideone.com/Obah0Y

Comment: Quando eu coloquei os dados direto na classe php ele funciona, e quando eu dou o post ele não funciona

Comment: @Thiago coloque aqui o resultado de `var_dump($jsonObj)`.

Comment: ela esta vazia: NULL

Comment: @Thiago tem de colocar mais código para percebermos melhor o problema. De onde vem o `$json` por exemplo?

Comment: Eu apenas dou um $.post( send, {"table": [{"d":1, "p":1, "m": "1"},{"d":2, "p":2, "m": "2"},{"d":3, "p":3, "m": "3"}]}, function( data ) {}, "json");
 do lado do cliente.

Comment: @Thiago consegui resolver o problema?

Comment: Não, no meu var_dump eu tenho o resultado postado string(38) "{\"nome\":\"alvaro\",\"idade\":\"34\"}"string(34) "{\"nome\":\"bia\",\"idade\":\"7\"}"string(36) "{\"nome\":\"alice\",\"idade\":\"2\"}"    mas não consigo acessar os dados separadamente

Comment: @Thiago e fez `var_dump` de quê? do `$jsonObj`? porque tem 3 aqui?

Comment: Eu acabei mudando meu metodo de $.post, agora eu recebo o Post,